# HTTP Caching VS Jquery Ajax Cache setting

Tags: jquery, ajax, http-caching

I've been discussing this matter with one of my colleague and we've agreed to a truce until on of us find the best answer concerning http cache.

The question is "What is the best practice regarding HTTP request cache considering that I use JQUERY ? Expires(and the likes) OR jquery.ajax.cache = false ?"

Is it faster/more effective to blindly cache random url strings produced by jquery to assure that dynamic content stays fresh OR is faster/more effective to set a valid HTTP Header so that the request won't be cached ?

Regards !

Comment: All ajax cache does is allow the webserver's client-side http caching strategy to work. For example, if the server is setting http expires headers, ajax cache false will allow those headers to do their job.